# Creating a new pandas dataframe column by looking up values in other rows

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to find a faster way to calculate the sales 52 weeks ago column for each product below without using iterrows or itertuples. Any suggestions? Input will be the table without "sales 52 weeks ago column" and output will be the entire table below.

```
         date  sales city product  sales 52 weeks ago
0  2020-01-01    1.5   c1      p1       0.6
1  2020-01-01    1.2   c1      p2       0.3
2  2019-05-02    0.5   c1      p1       nan
3  2019-01-02    0.3   c1      p2       nan
4  2019-01-02    0.6   c1      p1       nan
5  2019-01-01    1.2   c1      p2       nan
```

Example itertuples code but really slow:

```
for row in df.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
    try:
        df.at[row.Index, 'sales 52 weeks ago']=df[(df['date']==row.date-timedelta(weeks=52))&(df['product']==row.product),'sales']
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: You need tell us the logic and provide an example input and output dataset.

Comment: what if there are duplicates in the dates?

Comment: There won't be any duplicated dates for the same product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a merge after subtracting the date with  [`Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timedelta.html):

```
m=df['date'].sub(pd.Timedelta('52W')).to_frame().assign(product=df['product'])
final = df.assign(sales_52_W_ago=m.merge(df,
         on=['date','product'],how='left').loc[:,'sales'])
```

---

```
        date  sales city product  sales_52_W_ago
0 2020-01-01    1.5   c1      p1             0.6
1 2020-01-01    1.2   c1      p2             0.3
2 2019-05-02    0.5   c1      p1             NaN
3 2019-01-02    0.3   c1      p2             NaN
4 2019-01-02    0.6   c1      p1             NaN
5 2019-01-01    1.2   c1      p2             NaN
```